# How to follow up on answer with updated code?

Tags: support

I have a question about my Database Administrators Stack Exchange post: [Using NEXT clause to set periodic materilized view refresh in oracle and verifying refresh](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/176428/using-next-clause-to-set-periodic-materilized-view-refresh-in-oracle-and-verifyi)

If I want to follow up on my answer with my code, and ask about errors, how do I do that? In comments it doesnt allow to enter more than certain characters. Would answering your own post be the way to go?

Comment: Do you mean the answer you've got doesn't work for you and you want to ask about errors you get when applying it?

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not add this as an "answer" it's really an extension of the question.

You have at least two options:

1. **Edit the question**: You can always edit the question with additional information, and add a comment to the answer indicating that it hasn't resolved the issue.
2. **Ask a new question**: If the additional details you need to add are significant, or would change the focus of your original question, you can always ask a new question. You can include a link to the original question, plus whatever information would be necessary to provide detail on the second question.
3. **Chat with the answerer**: If you have enough reputation (or meet whatever other criteria would apply), you can invite the person who provided the answer that partially/almost worked to a chat. If you don't have sufficient reputation, but they may, you can ask them to start the chat. Or, pass enough info back and forth in the comments, and moving to a chat will be offered as an option. This gives you more options to directly communicate with the individual, and should allow more significant chunks of code to be exchanged.